# max_nesting_level issue in component upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento2, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

Magento 2:

I am trying to install an extension (same error for system upgrade also) and it fails at readiness check with below error:

PHP Settings Check

> Your current setting of xdebug.max_nesting_level=100. Magento 2
>   requires it to be set to 200 or more. Edit your config, restart web
>   server, and try again.

Here is the output snippet from `phpinfo();` I have already increased the value to 200, then 400 and then 10000.

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level    10000   10000
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Try set in apache2/php.ini, cli/php.ini and fpm/php.ini      
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by changing max_input_nesting_level to 400.